# CreateDC() method,while setting up a Printer fails for certain PRINTERs as well as in certain Windows Environment

Tags: c++, winapi, msdn

I have installed a HP Printer and added it to my list of Printer devices.
I am trying to use the following code:

```
    QString printerName = "HP Designjet 500 24+HPGL2 Card";
    DWORD infoSize, numBytes;
    HANDLE hPrinter;
    bool ok = OpenPrinter( ( LPWSTR )printerName.utf16(), ( LPHANDLE )&hPrinter, 0 );
    if ( !ok )
    {
        qErrnoWarning( "QWin32PrintEngine::initialize: OpenPrinter failed" );
        return;
    }
    GetPrinter( hPrinter, 2, NULL, 0, &infoSize );
    HGLOBAL hMem;
    hMem = GlobalAlloc( GHND, infoSize );
    PRINTER_INFO_2 *pInfo;
    pInfo = ( PRINTER_INFO_2* )GlobalLock( hMem );
    ok = GetPrinter( hPrinter, 2, ( LPBYTE )pInfo, infoSize, &numBytes );
    if ( !ok )
    {
        qErrnoWarning( "QWin32PrintEngine::initialize: GetPrinter failed" );
    }
    DEVMODE *devMode;
    devMode = pInfo->pDevMode;
    HDC hdc = NULL;
    hdc = CreateDC( NULL, ( LPCWSTR )printerName.utf16(), 0, devMode );
```

Now,the CreateDC() method fails.I even tried to return the Error using GetLastError() method, and it returned as "203",which corresponds to "ERROR_ENVVAR_NOT_FOUND".

I am completely clueless as of now.
I would be really glad,if someone can help me regarding this.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: 203 is a red herring, CreateDC() does not set an error code.

Comment: @Alex K.: Yeah,you are right. Thats the reason,I am completely clueless :(

Comment: Check `devMode` value. Reinstall printer driver. Check `PrintDlg` with `PD_RETURNDC` or `PD_RETURNDEFAULT`. Try `hdc = CreateDC( NULL, L"HP Designjet 500 24+HPGL2 Card", 0, devMode );`

Comment: @Daniel Sek: Reinstalling the Printer drivers does not seem to be viable option, because, I tried to run this code in various machines.And in many machines,it was not working properly. Then I tried your third option,but still it returns NULL :(.. Could you please some other alternatives.

Comment: So `devMode != NULL` and contains sensible values? Alternative: `PrintDlg` with `PD_RETURNDC` or `PD_RETURNDEFAULT` creates `HDC` in `hDC` field of `PRINTDLG`.

Comment: @Daniel Sek: Yes, devMode != NULL. I can even see all the parameters listed in devMode such as "Paper orientation ", "Paper width" etc. Sorry,I could not understand the alternative procedure exactly. I would be really glad,if you mention a sample code,which I can try. Thanks.

Comment: [https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/windows/desktop/dlgbox/using-common-dialog-boxes#displaying-the-print-dialog-box](https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/windows/desktop/dlgbox/using-common-dialog-boxes#displaying-the-print-dialog-box). Check if `PrintDlg` or `PrintDlgEx` also fails.

Comment: Just checked. Both PrintDlg as well as PrintDlgEx are working fine.

Comment: I have integrated your snipped in one of my program and it prints without any problems. Project is configured for wide characters (defined `UNICODE` and `_UNICODE`). Only change - I have removed `QString` and replaced it with `wchar_t*` and removed `qErrnoWarning`.

Comment: Oops, thats really wierd :(. Cannot understand, why its not working in my machine :(

Comment: @Daniel Sęk: Please let me know,if I can try some other alternatives to make it working